What will be the joint density $x_1,x_{(1)},$ and $y$, if $X_i\sim Exp(\mu,\sigma)$ for $i=1,2,...,n;$ $X_{(1)}=\min X_i$ and $Y=\sum (X_i-X_{(1)})$?
Suppose $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}$ be an iid from $Exp(\mu,\sigma)$ is the exponential distribution with location $\mu$ and scale $\sigma$ with probability density function
$$f(x;\mu,\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma}e^{-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}},~x\geq \mu,\mu\in\mathbb{R},~\sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{+}.$$
Let $X_{(1)}=\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\min}X_{i}$ and $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-X_{(1)}).$
Then we know that $(X_{(1)},Y)$ is complete sufficient statistics for $(\mu,\sigma),$ where $X_{(1)}\sim Exp(\mu,\frac{\sigma}{n})$ and $Y\sim G(n-1,\sigma),$ where $G(n-1,\sigma)$ is the gamma distribution with shape $n-1$ and scale $\sigma$ or one can say, the distribution with density
$$g(y;n-1,\sigma)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(n-1)\sigma^{n-1}}y^{n-2}e^{-\frac{y}{\sigma}}.$$
Now, my target is to derive the conditional density of $X_{1}$ given $X_{(1)}$ and $Y.$ Since $X_{(1)}$ and $Y$ are independent, their product of densities will be the joint density of $X_{(1)}$ and $Y.$ So only we need to derive the joint density of $X_{1},$ $X_{(1)}$ and $Y.$ The problem is $X_{(1)}$ and $Y$ are dependent on $X_{1}.$
Can anyone suggest to me how to proceed to obtain the joint density of $X_{1},$ $X_{(1)}$ and $Y.$
